# angular 9 keyPress event

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I want to have a counter for p:inputtextarea.

```html
<textarea rows="5"
  cols="100"
  maxlength="500"
  (keypress)="keyPress($event)"
  formControlName="message"
  class="form-control"
  pInputTextArea>
</textarea>

{{ this.message } of 500 characters
```

in ts file:

```js
message: string;

keyPress(event) {
    let a = event.code;
    console.log("KeyboardEvent " + a);
    this.message = a.length;
}
```

The value of a is Key+"anything entered" in IE and in chrome i get (keypress) is not a property.
Can someone help me point to the right way of doing this please?

Limit character count to 500. Update character count as user types
0 of 500 characters

Comment: Can you clarify why you are using keypress event specifically instead of something more widely supported such as keydown? If you try with event keydown does that help? If you review documentation for [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), you’ll see earnings of depreciation as well recommendation to use keydown instead.

Comment: @ Alexander Staroselsky i can use keydown, i was getting similar issue with IE key+"character entered". Can you please help with an exmaple.

Comment: You should create an example using something like https://stackblitz.com/ to help explain the issue. You also get the keypress is not a property when you change it to keydown?

Comment: This is a sample code I pasted here. I am just trying an example to understand how it works. Html just has the textarea and ts file has only the keypress event apart from imports and cosntructor

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking or what the issue is specifically. I’d start with reviewing the documentation for keydown: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event . Then changing the example to use that as well as the proper property for getting the key code.

Comment: When I click comment here I see below the textarea how many characters left as I type. I am trying the same with the textarea field in my html and trying the logic using keypress/keydown with the help of typescript by computing the length of characters typed.

Comment: The issue I face with keydown and keypress is console.log prints KeyA, KeyB ...for every letter typed. I am looking for examples that can help me

Comment: This site really isn't for examples, but do you mean something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbsir7

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky I will try this out

Comment: why not simply -if your form is called form-: `{{+(form.get('message').value?.length)}} of 500 characters` ?

Comment: @ Eliseo -  can you please explain. I do not undertand what the ? is for